# Create EDL file with ability to step back and forward frames

Tags: video, lua, video-processing, mplayer, video-editing

Right now I use MCEBuddy to automatically cut commercials and convert my recorded TV, but sometimes the commercial detection isn't the best, and I like to do it manually.

For this, I'm using mplayer with the -edlout option, which works fine.  However, I sometimes have to go back multiple times to get the cut where I want, and I can't step back frame by frame.  Mplayer doesn't seem to support this, but makes creating the edl files very easy.

I've recently found MPV, which apparently is derived from mplayer. It does have the option to step back frame by frame, as well as skip through the video with more granularity.  However, it doesn't seem to natively support creating edl files in the mplayer format like I need.

Is there an easy way to make either of these programs work how I want?  I saw that mpv allows you to use Lua scripts, but I've never worked with those and am not sure they'll allow me to do what i want.  I'm also not set on using either mplayer or mpv.  If you can suggest something better/easier that will get the job done, that's fine too.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [MPV Lua scripting](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/DOCS/man/lua.rst) would allow you to bind keys to Lua functions which can fetch (current) video properties and save them to a file. This way you could easily create your own custom [EDL](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/de/edl.html) file tool. [Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.html) isn't one of the hardest languages to learn.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have MCEBuddy, try using the MCEBuddy Custom Cuts tool included to mark the video cuts and create a EDL file.
It's granularity is limited to the resolution provided by the Windows DirectShow codecs it uses to display the video on the screen and mark locations.

Ref: https://www.facebook.com/479215282109210/posts/804598616237540/